# OracleDataReader reader.Read() starts to read rows from the second record row, skipping the first row record

Tags: c#, oracle, datareader, oledbdatareader

I have a SQL command and it returns 8 rows from the database.

When I use reader.Read() it starts at the second line, so I loose the fist row result. I don't know why it's skipping the first row record.

```cs
command.CommandText = "SELECT ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION, SUBSTR(ATTRIBUTE_DATATYPE, 2, 6) FROM " + proj.PID_Schema + "PIDD.ATTRIBUTES@" + proj.PID_Database + " WHERE " +
                "attribute_name LIKE 'Controller' " +
                "OR attribute_name LIKE 'Initials' " +
                "OR attribute_name LIKE 'IOType' " +
                "OR attribute_name LIKE 'NetworkType' " +
                "OR attribute_name LIKE 'SignalOutput' " +
                "OR attribute_name LIKE 'SignalInput' " +
                "OR attribute_name LIKE 'SPIInstrumentType' " +
                "OR attribute_name LIKE 'Substation' ORDER BY 1";

            try
            {
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        codelistsNumbersDict.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            connection.Close();

            return codelistsNumbersDict;
        }
```

Comment: **Use proper parameterization, do NOT concatenate data into queries.** See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements and https://bobby-tables.com. Also, you can use a verbatim string for your query `@"SELECT...` then you can use newlines in the string. Furthermore, don't swallow exceptions with an empty `catch` block, and always dispose connection, command, and reader with `using` blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have two reads:

```cs
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read(); // <--- FIRST READ (skipe first row)

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())  // <---- SECOND READ
    {
```

Because of this, you starting reading on second row.

If you take a look to [Retrieve data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) sample, it only has one read:

```cs
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                   // <-- No read here on sample!
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read()) // <-- Just ONE READ
    {
```

Doc screenshot:

[image: screenshot with the full code available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @dani-herrera's answer, you are calling `reader.Read()` twice.

Also, you don't need the `if (reader.HasRows)`, since if there are no rows the code inside the do loop won't execute.  If you need to know the rows processed, you can always add a counter.

```
            try
            {
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    codelistsNumbersDict.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                }
            }
```